# Playframework 2.0 in IntelliJ IDEA Routes File Association

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

What's the right file type for IDEA to pick up the Play Framework Routes file?

Answer (score 2):

### Enable Play2 Framework 2 Support Plugin

[image: IntelliJ 12 Play 2 Framework Plug-In]
* Make sure Play Framework support is not clicked(for Play Framework 1.0)

### HTML routing support for Play 2 Framework

[image: IntelliJ 12 Preferences -> File Types Association]

### IDEA Routes Context Menu

Mark the routes file with "Play 2 routing"
[image: Routes File Types Association Context Menu]

Answer (score 1):

**Html routing support for play 2 framework**:

[image: routing]

Comment: In Play the route file is just "routes" without the extension, so *.routes would not match up. I even added "routes" to the Registered Patterns but it is still not being recognized (i.e: I cannot cmd+click into the controllers or get IDE support on that file)

Comment: If you get the syntax highlighting like [here](http://img823.imageshack.us/img823/3040/e7ol.png), it's recognized correctly. Other features may be not supported yet.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was to right click on the routes file, then associate it with the Plain Text file type. Without this, it would re-indent all lines in the file.